# Convert a list of data frames to a flat data table in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a list of data frames as follows:

```
$E9.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.00688744
2 1320.2 0.00833458
3 1320.4 0.01035314
4 1320.6 0.01240330
5 1320.8 0.01468168
6 1321.0 0.01729148

$F12.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.02251423
2 1320.2 0.02667812
3 1320.4 0.03204212
4 1320.6 0.03841950
5 1320.8 0.04572450
6 1321.0 0.05349166

$H1.xls
    time   response
1 1320.0 0.02286131
2 1320.2 0.03130347
3 1320.4 0.04070016
4 1320.6 0.05163691
5 1320.8 0.06331903
6 1321.0 0.07704557
```

I want to convert it to a flat table as follows:

```
 E9.time E9.response  F12.time  F12.response  H1.time   H1.response
1 1320.0 0.00688744     ...         ...        ...         ...
2 1320.2 0.00833458
3 1320.4 0.01035314
4 1320.6 0.01240330
5 1320.8 0.01468168
6 1321.0 0.01729148
```

Briefly speaking, I want to stack them column by column (they have the same number of rows). Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bind_cols(dflist) %>%
  `colnames<-`(paste0(rep(names(dflist), each=2),".",colnames(dflist[[1]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all listed DFs have the same number of rows, then with library purrr (from tidyverse),

```
map_dfc(.x = your_list, .f = bind_cols)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The data format is right, but the names are not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `cbind` + `setNames` like below

```
setNames(u <- do.call(cbind,lst),paste0(rep(names(lst),each = 2),".",names(u)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The names I got from the code above are as follows: `"E9.xls.E9.xls.time"     "E9.xls.E9.xls.response" "F12.xls.F12.xls.time"     "F12.xls.F12.xls.response"  "H1.xls.H1.xls.time"     "H1.xls.H1.xls.response" `

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map`

```
  do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste0(y, names(x))), lst1, 
     sub("\\.xls", "", names(lst1))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The names I got from the code above are as follows: ` "E9.xls.E9time"     "E9.xls.E9response" "F12.xls.F12time"     "F12.xls.F12response" "H1.xls.H1time"    "H1.xls.H1response"`

Comment: @sophia You can unname the `Map` i..e `do.call(cbind, unname(Map(function(x, y), ..`